# SAP Shortcut file - How to redirect to specific transaction screen in SAP GUI?

Tags: shortcut, sap-gui

Problem : How to redirect the user to a specific executed transaction screen in SAP GUI?

Generated the SAP shortcut and able to redirect the user to specific transaction screen.
It is also possible to prefill the required input parameters.

The corresponding line in the shortcut is-

```
Command=AB12 RIWO00-input1=200001212;
```

where `AB12` is the transaction, and `input1` is the input parameter.

This will open that SAP screen, with `AB12` transaction and the input parameter would be filled with values.

But this mandates the user to clicks on enter explicitly/click on execute button explicitly after opening through the shortcut file.

Is it possible to include that enter also in the shortcut file?

Thank you :)

Comment: To find out the name of your specific input field (`RIWO00-input1` in the above example), select the field in SAP, hit F1, then the settings button (hammer icon) and use the `Screen Field` property.

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

Just add a * before the transaction/work flow specified - Thus the initial screen would be skipped if all the required input parameters are filled in.